# PHP Find word wrapped lines and unwordwrap

Tags: php, replace

I have this output(from another system) that I need the Test field to be on one line.
This stupid system wordwraps at 45 characters (with like 30 blank spaces before each line)

Here is my example output (that I need to input)

```
                      Name:
                      Pepsi
                      Test:
                      The Result was blah
                      and blah
                      Tester:
                      John

                      Name:
                      Sprite
                      Test:
                      The result was negative
                      Tester:
                      Jane

                      Etc etc
```

Sometimes the line after Test: gets word wrapped (some times not)
I need that line to be un-wordwrapped so I can import it in access.
The file is about 2mb, and there are a lot of instances that need to be cleaned up. That is why I am trying to write this script.

Thanks

----------------EDIT-------------

This is what I have come up with so far. But I cant get it to replace

```
<?php
function replace_newline($string) {
    return (string)str_replace(array("\r", "\r\n", "\n", "     ", "    ", "   ", "  "), ' ', $string);
}

function GetBetween($content,$start,$end){

    $r = explode($start, $content);

    foreach($r as $value){


        $t = explode($end, $value); //$t[0] between value

        $result = trim(preg_replace('/[\t\r\n]+/', ' ', trim($t[0])));

        $result = trim($result);
        $result = replace_newline($result);
        if ( !strstr($result, "Name:") ) {
            echo $result . "\r\n";
            $test = str_replace($t[0], $result, $test);
        }
    }


}
$test= file_get_contents("4321.txt");

GetBetween($test, "Test:", "Tester:");

?>
```

This outputs:
The Result was blah and blah
The result was negative

Comment: Are the 30 blank spaces actually spaces or are they tabs?

Comment: When you un-wordwrap the lines, should the newly added line be added as-is or include a space between them?

Comment: Honestly, I'd ask this on serverfault - there's some awesome awk/sed masters there

Comment: They are actually spaces. And I would like a space between them when they are un-wordwrapped.

Comment: I'm seeing a good bit of redundant code for cleaning up spaces.  Try this instead: `trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text))`.  It replaces all whitespace and whitespace blocks with a single space.

Comment: Just a heads up, I updated my original response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't working code, but you get the idea:

```
$cur = "";

foreach ($line as $l)
{
    if (strpos($l, ':') !== FALSE)
    {
        // Keep track of a new chunk
        if ( !empty(trim($cur)) ) { /* Write old data if not empty */ }

        // Start new chunk
        $cur = trim($l);
    }

    // Not a new chunk, add to end of last one
    $cur .= ' '. trim($l);
}

// Write the last chunk here

// Close file
```

You could probably do this whole thing with one crazy block of regex, but I'm not in the mood to work it out.

---

I know I said I wouldn't use regex, but here goes:

```
function getChunks($data)
{
    // Clean up whitespace
    $data = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data);

    // Create an anchor point before the label word
    $data = preg_replace('/\w+:/', '##\0', $data);

    // Separate the data into chunks based on anchors
    $sets = explode('##', $data);

    // Keep any and all chunks that aren't empty
    $sets = array_filter($sets, function($d) { return !empty(trim($d)); } );

    // array_filter() can damage the indexing, so return just the values
    return array_values($sets);
}
```

I haven't tested the code, but the comments should be a bit of guidance.
Note that this only works if 1) only labels contain a semicolon and 2) labels are only one word long.  Also, you won't want to run this on *massive* data sets.  It's not optimized for that sort of things.  It's optimized for quick-n-dirty.

Comment: I get an error on your code here:
    $sets = array_filter($sets, function($d) { return !empty(trim($d)); } );

Comment: That statement uses an anonymous function.  If your version of PHP is old enough, that kind of statement isn't supported, but you can always make the function separate and call it by name instead.